# More Efficient Bytes Conversion? - Android Xamarin C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, type-conversion, calculation

Does anyone know a more efficient way of doing this code:

```
public static float ConvertTrafficValues(double bytes, out string speedBytes)
    {
        if (bytes >= 1000000)
        {
            bytes /= 1000000;
            bytes = Math.Round(bytes, 1);
            speedBytes = "MB/s";
        }
        else if (bytes >= 1000)
        {
            bytes /= 1000;
            bytes = Math.Round(bytes, 0);
            speedBytes = "KB/s";
        }
        else
        {
            bytes = Math.Round(bytes, 0);
            speedBytes = "B/s";
        }

        return (float)bytes;
    }
```

Im calling this multiple times every second alongside with some other things and I need it to be as efficient as possible

Comment: This is more on topic for something like https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I dont use that site though - not even sure what that is about

Comment: It's for exactly these types of questions. Seems like a good time to start using it to me.

Comment: Calling this routine "multiple times every second" will be fine for efficiency and performance concerns.  Calling this function 100 times per second won't even raise the load on your CPU by any measureable amount.  We have similar code in our product to update the bitrate on a display...

Comment: The thing is that I need it to be battery-efficient, since it is a constant background task that it is being updated

Answer (score 0):

I coded the following solution based on the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488796/does-net-provide-an-easy-way-convert-bytes-to-kb-mb-gb-etc):

```
private static readonly string[] s_Suffixes = { "B/s", "KB/s", "MB/s" };

public static Single ConvertTrafficValues(Double bytes, out String speedBytes)
{
    if (bytes == 0.0d)
    {
        speedBytes = "B/s";
        return 0.0f;
    }

    Int32 magnitude = (Int32)Math.Log(bytes, 1024.0d);
    Double size;

    if (magnitude >= (s_Suffixes.Length - 1))
    {
        magnitude = s_Suffixes.Length - 1;
        size = bytes / Math.Pow(2.0d, magnitude * 10);
    }
    else
    {
        size = bytes / Math.Pow(2.0d, magnitude * 10);

        if (Math.Round(size, 2) >= 1000.0d)
        {
            magnitude += 1;
            size /= 1024.0d;
        }
    }

    speedBytes = s_Suffixes[magnitude];

    return (Single)size;
}
```

Even if it concerns file volumes, the underlying logic is almost the same. I limited the maximum magnitude to `Mb` since this is what your method is doing. I didn't change your implementation logics since you should know how and when to use the method much better than me.

Comment: After some tests in different orders with a million for loop cycles, your code seems to be much slower(570ms) vs the one I have wrote at first (110-120).
It might have something to do with `Math.Pow` maybe?