# How can I convert webclient ResponseHeaders["Content-Length" to bytes?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
client.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) => lblDownloadSize.Text = FormatBytes((client.ResponseHeaders["Content-Length"]).ToString());
```

And

```
private string FormatBytes(long bytes)
        {
            string[] Suffix = { "B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB" };
            int i;
            double dblSByte = bytes;
            for (i = 0; i < Suffix.Length && bytes >= 1024; i++, bytes /= 1024)
            {
                dblSByte = bytes / 1024.0;
            }

            return String.Format("{0:0.00} {1}", dblSByte, Suffix[i]);
        }
```

I want to display the file size either if it's in bytes or kb or mb or gb the problem is ResponseHeaders["Content-Length"] is long.  And if I'm doing :

```
client.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) => lblDownloadSize.Text = Convert.ToInt64(client.ResponseHeaders["Content-Length"]).ToString();
```

It will just show the file size as one long number.

Comment: what is the current output and what is the expected output

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488796/does-net-provide-an-easy-way-convert-bytes-to-kb-mb-gb-etc