# Format String into KB, MB and GB

Tags: android, string

Below is the class which returns me data counter value in String. I was wanted to format String into KB, MB, and GB

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView infoView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.traffic_info);
        String info = "";

        long getmobilerxbytes = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes();
        long getmobilerxpackets = TrafficStats.getMobileRxPackets();
        long getmobiletxbytes = TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
        long getmobiletxpackets = TrafficStats.getMobileTxPackets();

        long totalrxbytes = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes();
        long totalrxpackets = TrafficStats.getTotalRxPackets(); 
        long totaltxbytes = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes(); 
        long totaltxpackets = TrafficStats.getTotalTxPackets();

        info += "Mobile Interface:\n";
        info += ("\tReceived: " + getmobilerxbytes + " bytes / " + getmobilerxpackets + " packets\n");
        info += ("\tTransmitted: " + getmobiletxbytes + " bytes / " + getmobiletxpackets + " packets\n");

        info += "All Network Interface:\n";
        info += ("\tReceived: " + totalrxbytes + " bytes / " + totalrxpackets + " packets\n");
        info += ("\tTransmitted: " + totaltxbytes + " bytes / " + totaltxpackets + " packets\n");

        infoView.setText(info);
```

}

Here is beautiful method to do that :

```
public static String humanReadableByteCount(long bytes, boolean si) {
        int unit = si ? 1000 : 1024;
        if (bytes < unit) return bytes + " B";
        int exp = (int) (Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(unit));
        String pre = (si ? "kMGTPE" : "KMGTPE").charAt(exp-1) + (si ? "" : "i");
        return String.format("%.1f %sB", bytes / Math.pow(unit, exp), pre);
    }
```

But I am not sure how can i use above method in my onCreate code

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Call the method by passing the bytes . Add the String which is returned after doing the calculations to the TextView.

```
public static String getFileSize(long size) {
    if (size <= 0)
        return "0";

    final String[] units = new String[] { "B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB" };
    int digitGroups = (int) (Math.log10(size) / Math.log10(1024));

    return new DecimalFormat("#,##0.#").format(size / Math.pow(1024, digitGroups)) + " " + units[digitGroups];
}
```

Comment: @user574639 What do you mean "the counter is running very fast"?  How fast something runs in your app is nothing to do with Chiranjib's method, which is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Just use some mathematical formula shown below where you need:

```
if(bytes < 1024)
    return bytes + " bytes";

bytes /= 1024;
if(bytes < 1024)
    return bytes + " KB";

bytes /= 1024;
if(bytes < 1024)
    return bytes + " MB";

bytes /= 1024;
if(bytes < 1024)
    return bytes + " GB";

return String(bytes);
```

and to pass it to function

```
humanReadableByteCount(bytes,true);
```

where bytes equals TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes()

Hope it helps.
I found some link on stack too [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805826/actionscript-code-to-convert-bytes-to-kb-mb-gb-etc) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565704/how-to-correctly-convert-filesize-in-bytes-into-mega-or-gigabytes)

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass the `bytes` you get from `getTotal**Bytes()` to `humanReadableByteCount` method. And send `si` as true or false, depending on precision(like you want 1KB=1000 bytes or 1024 bytes).

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView infoView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.traffic_info);
    String info = "";

    info += "Mobile Interface:\n";
    info += ("\tReceived: " + TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes() + " bytes / " + TrafficStats.getMobileRxPackets() + " packets\n");
    info += ("\tTransmitted: " + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes() + " bytes / " + TrafficStats.getMobileTxPackets() + " packets\n");

    info += "All Network Interface:\n";
    info += ("\tReceived: " + TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes() + " bytes / " + TrafficStats.getTotalRxPackets() + " packets\n");

    info += humanReadableByteCount(TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes(),true);

    info += ("\tTransmitted: " + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes() + " bytes / " + TrafficStats.getTotalTxPackets() + " packets\n");

    info += humanReadableByteCount(TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes(),true);

    infoView.setText(info);
```

Comment: Can you actually show that into code ? I am editing my code in question.

Comment: Thanks user2550754. I got that...Silly changes it was

Comment: if it works then you should accept answer and upvote it. It would help in future for visitor to find answer.

Answer (score 0):

for KB:    `((float) Math.round((sizeInBytes / (1024)) * 10) / 10)`

for MB:    `((float) Math.round((sizeInBytes / (1024 * 1024)) * 10) / 10)`

for GB:    `((float) Math.round((sizeInBytes / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)) * 10) / 10)`