# How to get exact size of uploaded file?

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my code:

```
if (btnfileupload.HasFile)
{
    try
    {
        Int64 _size = 0;
        string strsize = null;
        int y = 0;

        _size = btnfileupload.PostedFile.ContentLength;

        strsize = _size.ToString();
        if (strsize.Contains("."))
        {
            y = strsize.IndexOf(".");
            strsize = strsize.Substring(0, y - 1);
        }

        Int64 _accountno = (Int64)Session["aco"];
        home h = new home();
        h._Account_number = _accountno;
        h._FileName = Path.GetFileName(btnfileupload.FileName);
        h._file_size = strsize;
        h._uploadDate = DateTime.Now;
        bool b = h.FileuploadSave(firstfilename);

        if (b)
            Response.Write("<script> aleart('File Uploaded') </script>");

        Fillgrid(null, null);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
}
```

`btnfileupload.PostedFile.ContentLength` return the size in bytes. The problem is if file size is 213.562 bytes then this property returns 213562 there is no dot(.) in return size. Please give me code that returns exact size.

Comment: A file cannot have a fractional number of bytes. I assume the dot is a thousands separator in your culture?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565704/how-to-correctly-convert-filesize-in-bytes-into-mega-or-gigabytes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565704/how-to-correctly-convert-filesize-in-bytes-into-mega-or-gigabytes)

Comment: FYI there's a typo in your `Response.Write`, it should be `alert` instead of `aleart`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET String.Format() to add commas in thousands place for a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105770/net-string-format-to-add-commas-in-thousands-place-for-a-number)

Answer (score 1):

```
strsize = _size.ToString();
if (strsize.Contains("."))
{
    y = strsize.IndexOf(".");
    strsize = strsize.Substring(0, y - 1);
}
```

That part of the code looks badly broken, even if the `ToString` result were to include `'.'` as a thousands separator, since it does not allow you to determine whether you're ending with bytes, kilobytes, megabytes, or gigabytes. If you always want to return kilobytes, you just need to divide by 1024:

```
sizeKB = _size / 1024;    // Rounds down to nearest kilobyte.
```

On the other hand, if you want to adapt your unit depending on the order of magnitude of the file, you'll need to include some additional logic.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think file size in bytes can have a decimal (correct me if I am wrong) unless they are converted into KB,MB etc

EDIT:
As Stijn said (.) is a separator in bytes

Comment: It's not a decimal, it's a thousands separator.

Comment: @Stijn isnt this what I said in answer ?? or should I be writing it more clearly ?

Comment: The problem isn't about a decimal separator. OP just wants a thousands separator, which can be achieved by the duplicate I linked. For example, if the file size is a hundred thousand bytes, OP wants *100.000 bytes* Your answer is technically correct, but doesn't answer the question.